# in which format i can Store Sound in Database using by C#

Tags: c#, audio, audio-recording

I'm using speech recognition but some words are not correct speaking. Therefore, I want mix my voice for some words.

I want to play a `String` in C#, some word I have recorded. I want to mix my recorded word with `String` and then play it.

Comment: so, you are saying you want to program a audio recorder/mixer? You want to record sound files with it and then mix them? And where does the database come into it?

Comment: yes i want mix my Voice with speech recognition

Comment: It is not clear if you want to store the _text_ or the resulting binary "sound" in the database. For space saving I would store the text and replay it in my application.

Comment: Ok, you want to record your voice, then run speech recognition, then run text to speech and then mix your voice with the text to speech output? what for? it will sound horrible!

Answer (score 3):

You would use a binary data type. For SQL Server, that type is named "image", for binary image (not for picture.)

With that you can store a .wav-file or .mp3 or whatever you need.

Of course, there is also a discussion whether you should store binary data in the database at all, or just store it on disk and store the path to the file in the database.